# Guide to install keystone on SAIO

Tags: jclouds, openstack-swift, keystone

I'm new to openstack, I have just installed and configured Swift using vmware. Followed this instruction: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html

Right now SAIO uses tempauth to authenticate, I am able to access the cloud using cURL and swift commands. But I'm trying to use jclouds to do the job instead: https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/#install

However, I can't make the tempauth work, some said its not supported.
I tried to find guides to install keystone auth instead, but to no avail; I already messed up the configuration of SAIO a few times.

Is there any good guide that follows the installation of SAIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a favour and skip SAIO, use DevStack instead.

Follow the instructions in this blog post

http://blog.phymata.com/2014/04/18/devstack-icehouse-on-the-rackspace-cloud/

It works just as well in a VMWare VM as in a Rackspace Cloud Server. If you really only want Swift+Keystone, delete all of the ENABLED_SERVICES lines except for

```
ENABLED_SERVICES=rabbit,mysql,key
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,s-proxy,s-object,s-container,s-account
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,horizon
```

I left Horizon in there as it can be helpful to have the dashboard handy.

You'll also want to delete the IMAGE_URLS lines. They won't be used.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use both of them together in VM. I'm new to this, so what do you mean by rackspace cloud server? I'm using Ubuntu 12

Comment: The instructions in the blog say to use a Rackspace Cloud Server. That's not really necessary. Just skip to step #4 and run those commands on your VMWare VM.